# update and retrieve in a single query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update the status field to "IN_PROGRESS" from "FAILED" to all the docs in one of the ElasticSearch index that matches this below query and retrieve updated docs.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": { "status": "FAILED" }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "count": { "gte": "2" }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "updated": { "gte": "now-2h" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can achieve this by two queries (update_by_query to update and GET to retrieve all  the updated docs). .The Problem is that I want to update and retrieve all the updated  docs in a single query  .
Is there any efficient way where I can perform this in a single query.

Comment: it is not possible in single query.

Comment: @SagarPatel the thing is I need all the docs that matches the above query first, then update the status field. What is the efficient way of doing this?

Comment: you can use updated by query API to update document and then use the _search API to get documents.

Comment: @SagarPatel is it possible to do something like below.
firstly retrieve all the docs where status="FAILED" using search api
secondly retrieve all ids from above _search api then perform update _bulk for that ids

Comment: yes you can do that , please chekc below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query with `"_source": false` which will return _id for all the documents.

```
POST multiapi/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status.keyword": {
        "value": "FAILED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From response you can get all the _ids and pass to the below [Ids query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html).

```
POST multiapi/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": ["M1BbcX4Bo1YkEVbN1wG1","NFBbcX4Bo1YkEVbN3gHm"]
    }
  },
   "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['status'] = 'IN_PROGRESS'"
  }
}
```

Also, if your index have large documents set then use [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) to retrive more then 10k documents.